# Connect existing database to mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed mysql on my laptop and copied my database folder to the default db folder. In mysql workbench I can see my new database and it's tables, but I cannot see any columns and I cannot query the tables, when I do that I get the error that table doesn't exist. What is wrong?

Comment: Hi Matthijs, what exactly do you mean by _copied my database folder to the default db folder_ ? Is this from another database instance? In that case you are better off making a database dump and importing it.

Comment: Oké, so the right way to transport a db to another server is to make a dump and than importing it?

Comment: yep, this is the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how well versed you are with MySQL, you can use either the MySQL Workbench to export and import data or use mysqldump. For MySQL Workbench, have a look at the manual here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html

To have full control, use mysqldump:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

Basically it works as follows. On the source computer, execute:

```
mysqldump --databases db1 db2 db3 > dump.sql
```

move the dump.sql to the target computer, and execute

```
mysql -u username -p -h 192.168.0.12 < dump.sql
```

(replace 192.168.0.12 with the mysql server IP address, username with a user that has enough rights)

The advantage of using mysqldump is that you can adapt the dump.sql (for instance change the database type, remove part of the data, etc.)

As always, take care when you are doing these kind of operations, make backups, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Moving files physically has been accepted practice in the past (only for MyISAM tables), but should not be used anymore to transfer a database. Instead export the data and import it in the new location. One way to do this is to take a dump (which is kinda snapshot of the current structure + data) and import that. Another way, especially with MySQL Workbench is migration. Start the migration wizard (via the Database menu), select a source db (connection), another one for the target, pick your objects you wanna transfer and follow the further steps. The data transfer is then done directly in the application.

If neither source nor target server are on the local machine then there is a speciality in MySQL Workbench. It can create proper import and export scripts you can directly run on your machines for export and import, readily made for the particular OS and server type. This is especially usefull if you are migrating from other db products (e.g. DB2 -> MySQL).